# Checking multiple content on the page using have_content in BDD

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, bdd, matcher

I want to test multiple data present on the website in a single scenario.

I don't want to use below line multiple times in my code to reduce code redundancy.
`expect(page).to have_content 'test1'`
`expect(page).to have_content 'test2'`

I found one more way of writing this in a single statement,for example,
`page.should(satisfy { |page| page.has_content?('test1') and page.has_content?('test2') })`

However, is there any better way to achieve this as I want to verify 10 such content on my website and I don't want the code to look very lengthy by repeating code.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have `and` operators in your condition then you can use `Enumerable#all?`

```
['test1','test2'].all? { |str| expect(page).to have_content str }
```

Comment: When I use the above code, it is getting passed with invalid values too. I wonder if we need to use anything else along with this like expect(page). or something similar?

Comment: You're right, I only showed you a way to put all your conditions together, as I'm not sure about the rest. I edited the answer, it should work "as is" now